# Network unreachable на Alpine в Virt-Manager

Tags: kvm, alpine-linux

Мне нужно создать сеть виртуальных машин (Alpine 3.18) в Virt-Manager, которые будут взаимодействовать с основной машиной (Ubuntu 20.04).
**На виртуальной машине Alpine**, при попытке задать маршрут происходит ошибка:

```
> route add default 192.168.100.1/24
route: ioctl 0x890b failed: No such device

> ping 8.8.8.8
ping: sendto: Network unreachable
```

**На основной, Ubuntu:**

```
> rfkill unblock wlan
virsh iface-list
 Name     State    MAC Address
--------------------------------------
 virbr0   active   52:54:00:d8:51:98
 wlp3s0   active   74:c6:3b:fd:c2:bd
```

Пытаюсь поднять все интерфейсы и соединения:

```
> ifconfig virbr1-nic up
nmcli connection up vnet0
Соединение успешно активировано (адрес действующего D-Bus: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/22)

> nmcli connection up virbr1
Соединение успешно активировано (master waiting for slaves) (адрес действующего D-Bus: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/20)
```

Типы соединений (нужны virbr0 и virbr1)

```
> nmcli connection show
NAME                    UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE  
TP-Link_3FD8            a9f97c36-68a7-4ac4-ba6d-d4c9c96a25de  wifi      wlp3s0  
docker0                 2301a9b4-8781-4092-b35b-377f755d759c  bridge    docker0 
virbr0                  c49a6b68-af10-4142-9bad-ac55aa0cc359  bridge    virbr0  
virbr1                  51204856-9b72-48cc-af73-61c4b7ef93d6  bridge    virbr1  
vnet0                   fbde81e6-820e-4bea-984d-67d530fb0948  tun       vnet0   

> ip addr show dev virbr1
20: virbr1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d4:ff:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Сети bridge1 соответствует virbr1, а default - virbr0:

```
> virsh net-list --all
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 bridge1   active   yes         yes
 default   active   yes         yes

> brctl show virbr1
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr1      8000.525400d4ff54   yes     virbr1-nic
```

Вывод ip a:

```
20: virbr1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d4:ff:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global noprefixroute virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: virbr1-nic: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr1 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:d4:ff:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

У обоих соединений стоит автозапуск при загрузке, перенаправление NAT. Подскажите, с чем может быть связано, делала такие же сети виртуальных машин Vmware, VirtualBox и таких ошибок не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мн помогла автонастройка `setup-alpine` на ВМ.